# python for loop parallel processing - appending data to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am have below step in my code which is taking around 45 to 50 mins to run (there are other steps which barely take few seconds)

So I am trying to optimize the execution/run time for this step it is essentially a for loop inside a function

```
def getSwitchStatus(dashboard: meraki.DashboardAPI,switches): 
    statuses = [] 
    #Establish the timestamp for midnight yesterday to enable collecting of yesterdays data 
    yesterday_midnight = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), time.min) - timedelta(days = 1) 
    for dic in switches:
        statuses.append(dashboard.switch.getDeviceSwitchPortsStatuses(dic['serial'],t0=yesterday_midnight)) 
    return statuses
```

Here is what I have tried to do so far

```
def switchsts():
    print("Inside switchsts")
    for dic in switches:
        statuses.append(dashboard.switch.getDeviceSwitchPortsStatuses(dic['serial'],t0=yesterday_midnight)) 


def getSwitchStatus(dashboard: meraki.DashboardAPI,switches): 
    print("Testing if switches is accessible")
    print("Switches type",type(switches))
    print("Switches",switches[0])

    p = Process(target=switchsts,args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
    return statuses
    print(statuses)
```

Unfortunately this is throwing an error here:

```
    for dic in switches:
```

> NameError: name 'switches' is not defined

Which is strange because I am able to print 'Switches' when the code reaches inside the getswitchstatus function but somehow the function that I am trying to parallelize doesnt seem to read it.

Inside switchsts
Process Process-1:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
> self.run()
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> File "C:\Sample_project\venv\ciscomeraki_file_parallelprocessing.py", line 83, in switchsts
> for dic in switches:
> NameError: name 'switches' is not defined

P.S.: I am new to parellel processing so I am guessing I am making some rookie mistake

****Edit1*** Adding code for 'switches'

```py
def getSwitches(dashboard: meraki.DashboardAPI,orgID, network_id=False): 
    if network_id is False or network_id is None: 
        devices = dashboard.organizations.getOrganizationDevices( 
            orgID, 
            total_pages='all', 
            productTypes='switch' 
        ) 
        return devices 
    else: 
        devices = dashboard.organizations.getOrganizationDevices( 
            orgID, 
            total_pages='all', 
            productTypes='switch', 
            networkIds=network_id 
        ) 
        return devices
```

Comment: Please make sure the code in your question has propper indentation.

Comment: Maybe I've missed something, but to me it seems that neither the code in the question nor the proposal in the answer contain substantial parallel processing (just _one_ additional process started)? Shouldn't you look into a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)? (The question isn't clear enough for me to decide if that would help.)

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that your switchsts() fucntion have not switches in it.

so try this if it works:

```
def switchsts(switches):
    print("Inside switchsts")
    for dic in switches:
        statuses.append(dashboard.switch.getDeviceSwitchPortsStatuses(dic['serial'],t0=yesterday_midnight)) 

def getSwitchStatus(dashboard: meraki.DashboardAPI,switches): 
    print("Testing if switches is accessible")
    print("Switches type",type(switches))
    print("Switches",switches[0])

    p = Process(target=switchsts, args=(switches,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    return statuses
    print(statuses)
```

Comment: tried that                                                                                                                      
             def switchsts(switches):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   
                 TypeError: switchsts() takes 1 positional argument but 175 were given

Comment: the 'switches' is essentially a list with 175 items

Comment: define switches globally. Or can you share code code also here?

Comment: have added the code for switches in original code , its gets called as switches = getSwitches(dashboard,orgID)

Comment: p = Process(target=switchsts, args=(switches,))

Comment: Thanks the error is gone now, however the main objective still remains the for loop is still taking time 45- 50 mins for execution

Comment: i have updated the answer as required.